# Accessing private members from mocked object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

In my project we have a repository of test data which is used for integration testing. This repository is then used to create a mock unit of work which can be called upon by methods being tested. I'm having an issue trying to get access to perform the assert on.

The data I would like to assert is held inside `source`

[image]

I've been looking into accessing non-public members using reflection but the following returns `null`:

`PropertyInfo pInfo = vms.GetType().GetProperty("SourceInterface", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);`

Replacing `SourceInterface` with `source` also returns null

Is there a way I can retrieve the `SourceInterface` objects from `source`?

EDIT:
Test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAllVMS_VMSReturned()
{
    IEnumerable<SourceInterface> vms = controller.GetAllVMS();
    Assert.IsTrue(vms.ToList().Count > 0); //Throws NullReferenceException 
}
```

Method under test:

```
public IEnumerable<SourceInterface> GetAllVMS()
{
    return database.SourceInterfacesRepository.GetAll();
}
```

Comment: I'll add my method under test along with the test call too

Comment: Based on code sample `vms` is IEnumerable... It makes absolutely no sense to expect some custom methods on it. Probably bad copy-paste - make sure to provide [MCVE] that looks plausible.

Comment: There really is nothing more to add to the question; the only other information which I could possibly provide would be the set-up for our unit of work (in this example: database) which has been injected before the test takes place.

Comment: Based on accepted answer your question has absolutely nothing to do with mocking, unit testing or code you've provided. You may want to edit it with [MCVE] that matches answer (i.e. basic `.Where(...)` call on an array and reflection call to get source)... (You obviously understand that digging into implementation details of LINQ helper classes is not the way to write unit tests, so no comments on that)

Comment: I think we've got our wires crossed... My question is based on the knowledge I had at the time of writing (as you can see from my lower rep, I'm still very much learning), hence the incorrect title/assumption my problem was with mocking on my part. I'll take a look at the link and edit my post to reflect it, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is not a property but a field. Do this:

```
FieldInfo[] privateFields = vms.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

You can then filter the `privateFields` based on whatever you need.

Comment: Many thanks! I was able to get access to the fields after adding this